# Unable to locate the checkboxes in excel - win32com.client package

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, pywin32

I am trying to pull the rows from an excel for which the checkbox is ticked, using python.

Sample code I have used is:

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')              
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)              
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")              
            
# Get the values of all the checkboxes in the worksheet              
cb_dict = {}              
for cb in ws.CheckBoxes():              
    cb_dict[cb.Name] = cb.Value            
    # Check if checkbox value is 1.0 and get the cell location            
    if cb.Value == 1.0:            
        cell = ws.CheckBoxes(cb.Name).TopLeftCell            
        # Get the values of columns A and B based on the cell address    
        client_name = ws.Range("A" + str(cell.Row)).Value    
        ledger_no = ws.Range("B" + str(cell.Row)).Value
```

I noticed that, it started to pull too many checkboxes, and when I went to inspect the excel, I found that there are 300+ checkboxes that are present in the selection pane while only 14 are visible as shown below.

[image: Excel Image]

There are 100's of excel file that I need to process and I fear most of them have this scenario.

1. How can I find where the checkboxes are located (I tried, hide/unhide etc)
2. Is there any workaround I can run in my script to bypass the unwanted checkboxes?

Any links or workaround would be helpful.

Comment: Let me guess: Those checkboxes where added with a code, and the code was executed multiple times, so there are multiple checkboxes on top of each other.

Comment: Hi @FunThomas 
I am not sure about that. I am just using python script to retrieve values from the excel. And when I opened the sheet and inspected, found these checkboxes. My only assumption is the excel sheet could be corrupted/damaged. But I still need to process 100s of these excels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already written as comment: I assume those checkboxes where added via code, and the code was executed multiple times, so there are multiple checkboxes on top of each other.

You can check if a checkbox is painted *above* another by comparing the property `zOrder`. A lower value means the checkbox is *below* another checkbox.

If two (or more) checkboxes are exactly on top of each other, the user will see only the topmost checkbox. Consequently, only the topmost checkbox can be selected (or deselected), and you will be interested only in those checkboxes.

The following (VBA) code will loop over all checkboxes and check if it is a "topmost" checkbox. You can decide by your own what to do with the "extra" checkboxes: You can delete or just ignore them (when you delete them: You should make a backup of the files before...)

```
Sub MyCheckboxes()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes  ' Change this to access the correct worksheet.
        If CheckIfThereIsACheckboxOnTop(ws, cb) Then
            Debug.Print "I am hidden: " & cb.Name, cb.Value, cb.ZOrder
            ' cb.Delete  ' Activate to get rid of it.
        Else
            Debug.Print "I am on top: " & cb.Name, cb.Value, cb.ZOrder
            ' Do whatever you want to do with the checkBox
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function CheckIfThereIsACheckboxOnTop(ws As Worksheet, cbToCheck As CheckBox)
    ' Return True if there is another Checkbox above the current
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    
    For Each cb In ws.CheckBoxes
        If cbToCheck.TopLeftCell.Address = cb.TopLeftCell.Address _
        And cbToCheck.ZOrder < cb.ZOrder Then
            CheckIfThereIsACheckboxOnTop = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

I have to leave it up to you to translate this to Python code, however, I think you get the idea.

Just for information: Same is true also for other form controls (eg optionButtons or Buttons). It is true for all shapes, however, to check the zOrder of any shape, you need to use the property  `zOrderPosition`.

Comment: Thank you so much. cb.ZOrder saved it for me. 
cb.Visible is True for those hidden ones and cb.Value is also set as 1.0. 
Used combination of cb.Name and cb.ZOrder to get the job done.
Only difference was, User was seeing the "lowermost" checkbox. ZOrder helped me to order it and I just removed the rest of it for my data extract. 

Thanks again

Comment: @nikviz We here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the offered solution works... So, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you so much. I have marked it now :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there (really) are hidden check boxes (as shapes) on the respective sheet. I also suppose that you can see in `Selection pane` other check boxes, too, but having the visibility marked as a strikeout (by a kind of backslash) eye icon...  If my suppositions are correct, you can use the next function to return only the visible check boxes (in an array). I will try showing the VBA equivalent (to be `translated` in python):

```
Function ReturnVisibleCheckBoxes(ws As Worksheet) As Variant
        Dim arrCb() As CheckBox, sh As Shape, i As Long
        
        ReDim arrCb(ws.Shapes.count)
        
        For Each sh In ws.Shapes
            If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
                If sh.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                    If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Visible Then
                        Set arrCb(i) = sh.OLEFormat.Object: i = i + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If i > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrCb(i - 1): ReturnVisibleCheckBoxes = arrCb
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testReturnVisibleCheclBox()
   Dim arr() As CheckBox, ws As Worksheet, cb
   Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use there the sheet you need
   
   arr = ReturnVisibleCheckBoxes(ws)

   For Each cb In arr
       If cb.Value = 1 Then
            Debug.Print cb.name, cb.TopLeftCell.address
       End If
   Next cb
End Sub
```

No error handling for the case of no any such check box, but it would be not complicated to build.